# Стилизация меню выбора языка

Tags: html, css

Столкнулся с следующей проблемой.Нужно сделать выпадающие меню с выбором языка.Проблема в том,что этот список не получается стилизовать.Как это можно сделать без костылей?

Comment: *лучше всего* не работает в IT.. здесь нужен индивидуальный подход с хотя бы каким-нибудь описанием предметной области... В Вашем же вопросе совершенно не раскрыто, что у Вас есть и что вы хотите получить в итоге.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: Интересно, почему не получатся...????????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

если вы уперлись именно в `<select>`, то никак или очень ограниченно. А если нет, то сделайте выбор языка, например, так: 
сама выбирашка - набор инпутов типа `radio` и их лейблов
выпадание оной - заверните ее в div, который будет, скажем, ограничен по высоте до размеров стандартного селекта, а  в нем еще div, который спозиционирован абсолютно и в обычном состоянии торчит за пределы родителя вниз (в нем и будет список -выбирашка). По дефолту див-родитель имеет стиль `overflow:hidden;`, при наведении мыши - `overflow:visible;`.

Ну или jQuery UI вам в помощь.